# Why enable a yum repo it isn't permanent

Tags: centos7, yum

I'm new in Centos (7) distrib (I come from debian) and I don't understand something.

Why when I try to enable a repo, this is not permanent ? I mean, when I reboot the server, the `yum update` doesn't check the repo previously enable.

I tried with :

- `yum-config-manager --enable runner_gitlab-runner` for example
- set `enabled` to 1 in `/etc/yum.repos.d/runner_gitlab-runner.repo`

  (I have the same behaviour with epel repo, docker repo , etc...)

So is this not the way to do this?

Comment: Most probably it is working ok, but not displaying all the repos because it already has all necessary information in **cache** . Be sure that repos are enabled, `yum repolist` will list all enabled ones. You can clear cache an try again first `yum clean dbcache`, than 'yum update'.

Comment: Ok, I did the clean dbcache and it work now. So thank for that tricks ;)